# How can I get the installed GDAL/OGR version from python?

Tags: python, gis, geospatial, gdal, ogr

How can I get the installed GDAL/OGR version from python?

I aware of the `gdal-config` program and are currently using the following:

```
In [3]: import commands

In [4]: commands.getoutput('gdal-config --version')
Out[4]: '1.7.2'
```

However, I suspect there is a way to do this using the python API itself.  Any dice?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**`gdal.VersionInfo()`** does what I want:

```
>>> osgeo.gdal.VersionInfo()
'1604'
```

This works on both my Windows box and Ubuntu install.  `gdal.__version__` gives an error on my Windows installation, although it works on my Ubuntu installation:

```
>>> import osgeo.gdal
>>> print osgeo.gdal.__version__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__version__'
```

Comment: Current invocation, circa 2020s, is `python -c "from osgeo import gdal;print(gdal.__version__)"`  (command line example since it has better formatting in a comment)

Answer (score 16):

The `__version__` property in the osgeo.gdal module is a string that contains the version number

```
import osgeo.gdal
print osgeo.gdal.__version__
```

On my ubuntu machine gives:

```
>> '1.6.3'
```

Comment: on python3, use:
`print (osgeo.gdal.__version__)`