# View which non-python package is installed in dataflow

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dataflow

How can one view which non-python library version is installed in dataflow? E.g.

```
gdal-config --version
```

Note: I can't use `import osgeo` because the problem is that currently dataflow throws module not found error (osgeo not found) when trying this: `from gdal import osr` or `from osgeo import osr`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the installed GDAL/OGR version from python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233674/how-can-i-get-the-installed-gdal-ogr-version-from-python)

Comment: I can't import osgeo, because this is an issue with loading gdal to dataflow

Comment: If you can get the tarball of `osgeo`, you can use `--extra_package` parameter pointing to said tarball when submitting the job to Dataflow. (Looks like the tarball is accessible at this link https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/releases/download/v3.4.1/gdal-3.4.1.tar.gz)